# Question about HTTP.SYS and SSL traffic

Tags: iis-7, ssl, httplistener

1) Why when using SSL over HTTP must we configure HTTP.SYS protocol listener to allow SSL trafic on particular port, but we are not required to configure NET.TCP listener when using SSL over TCP?

2) 
a) Is HTTP.SYS installed together with IIS, or does it exist independently of IIS?

b) If it is a part of IIS, then which HTTP listener is intercepting HTTP requests if IIS ( and thus HTTP.SYS ) is not installed on the system?

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as SSL over HTTP. There is only HTTP over SSL over TCP, also known as HTTPS. You can also do other protocols over SSL, like SMTP and IMAP. But you certainly don't do SSL over IMAP.

Comment: All resources on WCF that I've read used the terms SSL over TCP and SSL over HTTP when trying to make a distinction between the two ( I'm aware that HTTP runs on top of TCP )

Comment: Then they are all wrong.

Comment: This is just me guessing, but I think the resources distinguish between the two due to the fact that traffic over HTTP is handled by different protocol listener ( HTTP.SYS ) than one used for trafic over TCP ( Net.Tcp port sharing service ).

Answer (score 2):

1. SSL over TCP still requires the TCP port to be open. You can do SSL traffic on port 12345; if you really wanted to. You just need the port open that is expecting inbound connections. I'm not 100% what is being asked here; can you elaborate?
2. HTTP.SYS is a driver; it is part of the Window's Operating System. Things other than IIS could use it.

HTTP.SYS exists for a few reasons:

1. Kernel level caching.
2. Logging.
3. QoS

Comment: I'm simply curious why I need to configure HTTP.SYS (via tools like netsh) to allow SSL traffic on particular port, while I don't have to configure NET.TCP listener to allow SSL traffic. Instead, NetTcpBinding can immediatelly start SSL connection on particular port (assuming this port is free)

Comment: @User: HTTP.SYS does not care about TCP traffic; only HTTP traffic. HTTP.SYS is what is listening for the request on that given port. When using TCP; it's whatever program (Like WAS) is listening on the port.

Comment: Please re-read my question - I didn't say HTTP.SYS cares about TCP traffic.